# Should I always use the 'in' parameter modifier when possible?

Tags: c#, performance

I was searching about differences between `out`, `ref` and `in` parameter modifiers when I found this [in Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier):

> The in keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference.[...] It is like the ref or out keywords, except that in arguments cannot be modified by the called method.

So this means that the 'in' modifier is like a 'readonly ref' modifier, right? So, should I always use the 'in' parameter modifier when I don't need to modify its value to get the best performance?

Comment: That's what the documentation says... *"Defining methods using `in` parameters is a potential performance optimization. Some struct type arguments may be large in size, and when methods are called in tight loops or critical code paths, the cost of copying those structures is critical. Methods declare in parameters to specify that arguments may be passed by reference safely because the called method does not modify the state of that argument. Passing those arguments by reference avoids the (potentially) expensive copy."*

Comment: Although there is the note: *"Because `int` is no larger than a reference in most modern machines, there is no benefit to passing a single `int` as a readonly reference."*

Comment: Since `ref` and `out` are same during runtime, I guess same to the `in` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitively get a close look to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier) and use the `in` modifier for specific use case that you can find into your code path / profiling / optimization.

Remember that, 'best performance' is usually meaningless out of it's context. :)